# ThinkPad Fan Control not working properly

Tags: thinkpad, fan

I have Lenovo ThinkPad W500.  I have Ubuntu 12.10 installed. Its fan was not running at full speed, so I installed ThinkPad Fan Control software (tpfc0.5).  I launch it by executing tpfc_start.sh in terminal and entering my password. 
Here's a screenshot of the program:
https://www.mediafire.com/?76yc1qnmkcn30vh

When I try to set the fan speed by either Automatic Control or Manual Control, the fan goes to full speed for about 5 seconds, and then it goes back to slow speed. Is there something that I'm missing? Please help me so that the fan remains at full speed all the time until I set it down to a low speed.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm owner of Thinkpad W500 too, running Ubuntu 14.10

Use terminal to create or modify file **/etc/thinkfan.conf** with:

```
sudo nano /etc/thinkfan.conf
```

My file contains:

```
sensor /proc/acpi/ibm/thermal (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

(0, 0 , 51) 
(1, 50, 52)
(2, 51, 55)
(3, 54, 58)
(4, 56, 66)
(5, 64, 70)
(6, 68, 80)
(7, 79, 86)
(127, 84, 32767)
```

and **/etc/modprobe.d/thinkpad_acpi.conf** should contain:

```
options thinkpad_acpi fan_control=1
```

If you didnt load kernel module you should run this command:

```
sudo modprobe thinkpad_acpi
```

when done start to play with GUI interface -if needed (heard about it but I don’t use it).